# How can I handle async call in drawer's listview with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Drawer with listview and I don't like to display a listviewItem if an async call (Future) says that page/step is already done. Each Listview is a separate Widget function and for example registration is already done I don't want to display. Where (and how) I have to put the async call?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to hide the listview item or do you want to prevent navigating to that listview item's screen?

Comment: Hide (Or be more specific miss out that widget). I know Visibility, but how to provide them a bool value from async database call?

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the ListView with a `FutureBuilder` like this and provide a function which returns a Future.

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fetchDataFromDb(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    visible: snapshot.data[0].completed != true,
                    child: itemList(),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: snapshot.data[1].completed != true,
                    child: registration(),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Here instead of `future: _fetchDataFromDb()`, provide your future which fetches data from db and returns which all items are completed.

This way you can run async operations before the ListView is drawn on the screen.

---

In your case, extract each item into a StatefulWidget. Then make the async call in initState(). After getting results, call setState(). Based on the results, use Visibility widget to change show or hide the ListItem.

See the sample code below

```
class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ItemList> createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  late List<bool> completedList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: completedList[i] != true,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          "Registration",
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCompleted();
  }

  void fetchCompleted() async {
    var result = await db.fetchCompleted();
    setState(() {
      completedList = result;
    });
  }
}
```

Similarly, create another StatefulWidget for registration.

Comment: Yes, I use it when displaying list data in a listView (items for example)

But in a drawer, the items provided separetely from Widget functions. Registration(), Items(),  Orders() that handles click event separately.

Comment: Can you post the code of your drawer?

Comment: ```return Drawer(
        child: ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), children: <Widget>[
      itemList(),
     registration()]);```

Comment: ```Widget registration() {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("Registration",
      onTap: () {
      },
    );
  }```

Comment: Edited answer, give a try.

Comment: your snapshot.data is from a db table as a list. And I would like to hide registration() Widget when another db table says registration is already done. Or the itemList() Widget when items.Count()>20 for eaxample. Different db calls.

Comment: Edited based on input from comments